# MyISAM Performance: Join Decomposition?

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam

in [High Performance MySQL](http://www.amazon.de/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Load-Balancing/dp/0596101716/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1300750585&sr=1-1) on page 159 they talk about breaking up complex queries into simple ones:

Converting

```
SELECT * FROM tag
JOIN tag_post ON tag_post.tag_id=tag.id
JOIN post ON tag_post.post_id=post.id
WHERE tag.tag='mysql';
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag='mysql';
SELECT * FROM tag_post WHERE tag_id=1234;
SELECT * FROM post WHERE post.id in (123,456,567,9098,8904);
```

And sort of doing the actual join yourself in your application.

My Question is wether this is stil such a good idea when the final query has a where-clause with a few thousand IDs it needs to match (the actual table itself has about 500k entries).

What I mean is, will there be a big penalty for having a query like

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE post.id in (123,456,567, ... <a few thousand IDs here> ... ,9098,8904);
```

instead of the join-statement above? Would it help to move this logic to Stored Procedures inside the Database (while considering how poorly stored procedures are implemented in MySQL)?

Comment: See the following link for a performance comparison between a large IN clause and a temporary join table. http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/

Comment: thanks, that page was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join decomposition is useful in certain situations, but in most situations the joins are going to be faster.

In your case, I would stick with the joins instead of passing in a few thousand IDs in an IN clause.

Comment: Could you please explain why the joins are going to be faster?