# How to use sub select mysql queries in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573747/join-decomposition-inside-php), i came to know that sub select is far better than or somewhat better than joining multiple tables and comparatively better than using small queries.

And according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in) the answer seems to be for laravel 4.

Is sub select queries great in performance when it comes to laravel 5.x?

If so how may i use it on join queries in a feasible and efficient way?

Comment: My advice regarding Laravel and MySQL is to just focus on what is optimal from a MySQL point of view, at least for queries.  Correlated subqueries (an alternative to a join) usually do _not_ perform as well as their corresponding joins.

Comment: right now i use join's. But after the articles i mentioned i am thinking otherwise since it has a valid point